# Find columns with the same values rearranged

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, comparison

I want to find values in two columns that differ only in the rearrangement of values between columns. And where matching values are found (for example: 3-b / b-3 and a-3 / 3-a) in case of finding the second event - put down the unit.
It is necessary in order to be able to exclude duplicates from the data frame. It is desirable without loops, since there are a lot of rows

```
import numpy as np


table = pd.DataFrame({'id_1': [a, 2, 2, b, 3, 3],
                  'id_2': [3, 4, 5, 3, b, a],})

Result_table=pd.DataFrame({'id_1': [1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3],
          'id_2': [3, 4, 5, 3, 2, 1],
          'Result':[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]})

>>> Result_table 
  id_1  id_2    Result
0   a   3   0
1   b   4   0
2   b   5   0
3   b   3   0
4   3   b   1
5   3   a   1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create `Series` object with applying `frozenset` on rows and group them

```
>>> df
   id_1  id_2
0     1     3
1     2     4
2     2     5
3     2     3
4     3     2
5     3     1
>>> df["Result"] = df.groupby(df.agg(frozenset, axis=1)).cumcount()
>>> df
   id_1  id_2  Result
0     1     3       0
1     2     4       0
2     2     5       0
3     2     3       0
4     3     2       1
5     3     1       1
```

Answer (score 2):

First we use `np.sort` to sort over the rows, so `3, 1` becomes `1, 3`.
Then we use `groupby.cumcount` to give a flag for each same row:

```
dft = pd.DataFrame(np.sort(table, axis=1), columns=table.columns)
df['Result'] = dft.groupby(['id_1', 'id_2']).cumcount()

   A  B  Result
0  1  a       0
1  1  a       0
2  2  b       0
3  3  c       0
4  3  c       1
5  4  d       1
```

Comment: thanks for you your answer, but I mean another problem. in table we have 0 row (1 3) and 5 row (3 1), which has exactly values in different columns. I want to find this situations

Comment: So you want: `df = pd.DataFrame(np.sort(table, axis=1), columns=table.columns).drop_duplicates()` Then `print(df)`?